# Substitue and matched expression in a regex perl

Tags: regex, perl, string-substitution

I have a HTML file which has many expression like

```
/v/global/nagargaurav/CALL::ROWS_ARE_MATCHED.log
```

I have my code like this

```
my $dir = /v/global/nagargaurav/;

$html =~ s/$dir\\/(.*?)::(.*?)\.log/$1 : $2/g;

print $html;
```

it gives the output -

```
CALL : ROWS_ARE_MATCHED
```

But what i need is to output like this

```
**CALL : ROWS ARE MATCHED**
```

and there are many such lines but the expression is same.
can anybody help me with this.

Comment: Did you *really* run exactly this expression: `s/$dir\\/(.*?)::(.*?)\.log/$1 : $2/g` and got output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $html = '/v/global/nagargaurav/CALL::ROWS_ARE_MATCHED.log';
my $dir  = '/v/global/nagargaurav/';

$html =~ s/$dir\/(.*?)::(.*?)\.log/$1 : $2/g;
$html =~ s/_/ /g;

print $html;
```

Answer (score 0):

Possible in one step by using /e:

```
$html =~ s{ $dir /? ([^:]+) :: ([^.]+) \.log }
          { do{ local$_=$2;y/_/ /;"$1 : $_"} }gsex;
```

Result:

```
CALL : ROWS ARE MATCHED
```

BTW, your declarations are not Perl, these should read:

```
my $html = '/v/global/nagargaurav/CALL::ROWS_ARE_MATCHED.log';
my $dir  = '/v/global/nagargaurav/';
```

or similar.

Regards

rbo